# using self signed certificate on mobile data plan

Tags: android, ssl, tomcat7, self-signed

Short story: I am experiencing different android app behaviors based on whether I'm on wireless or mobile data. This looks related to using https with self signed certificate.

Long story: I have a tomcat instance running, configured with an SSL connector and a self signed certificate. It all works great. I can access it using https from my desktop and from my android app. For the android app, I had to use BKS to hold the cert but I managed to get that working too. The problem? When I switch my phone to mobile data, I get the following failure:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN'
    'http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd'>
    <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
    <title>The request failed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p><big>The request is not understood.</big></p>
    <p>
    <i>Technical description:</i><br/>400 Bad Request - Check your spelling for the requested URL</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried to access the same url my app request from chrome running on the phone, and got this error:

```
Error 111 (net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED): Unknown error.
```

**I see no issue at all if i use wifi. The issue reproduces consistently on mobile data. My provider is at&t. Any ideas?**

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same problem. How odd